# How to reenter Linux process after closing putty

Tags: linux, putty

I'm new to Linux.Yesterday I wrote some Python codes,now I'm using Linux to execute my codes,it may take a few hours.  As my Linux is not native,it's a remote server,I use putty to connect to it.
Now ,I want to close putty and go to sleep.But I don't know how to find my process again and reenter it after I wake up and start putty.And also,I wrote some code to print progress rate，next time when I find the process,can I see the print info again?

Comment: You want to install `screen` (if it isn't already installed) on the remove server and start screen after you ssh into the remove using putty. You can then start the process and detach with `ctrl+d` go to sleep, wake up and reattach with `screen -R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `screen`, start your programm and close the connection. After logging in again, use `screen -r` to resume your session.

Alternatively `nohup` will do the trick.

Comment: This post provides step by step instruction to do it on a Linux machine. https://pushprajsingh05.wordpress.com/2018/10/05/add-screen-to-your-linux-centos-machine

Answer (score 0):

`screen` is the best built-in tool that's always available for that, although it gets a bit weird around keyboard shortcuts, some of which sometimes don't work the way you want exactly.

I've found `tmux` to be much better in terms of usability.

Alternatively. take a look at [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/), which is trying to replace `ssh`. It's a mobile shell tool from MIT that supports intermittent connectivity, lots of praise there.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I'll try later!